# Guzzle Installation

Tags: symfony, guzzle

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error :

```
php composer.phar require guzzle/guzzle:~3.7
```

Error :

```
    ./composer.json has been updated
     Loading composer repositories with package information
     Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
     Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is  missing from your system.
    - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle ~3.7 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any idea ??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use guzzle/guzzle through a bundle if you are using symfony.

I recommend you to use misd/guzzle-bundle. So, add this line on your composer.json

```
"misd/guzzle-bundle": "1.1.*@dev"
```

Then, update your bundles:

```
php composer.phar update
```

And you will get the last version of  guzzle/guzzle.

Dont forget to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 4):

> guzzle/guzzle v3.8.1 requires ext-curl * -> **the requested PHP extension curl is  missing from your system**.

Just install [cURL extension](https://php.net/curl). On Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`. Don't forget to restart your web server/PHP process.